# Is it possible to define abstract composite symbols in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to use the symbols

```
from sympy import *
phi,p,R,n,x1,k,f = symbols('phi,p,R,n,x1,k,f')
```

to write an abstract function

```
f = R(phi) - p * n * R(phi)**2 * x1 - k * cos(R(phi)) (1)
```

and compute its first derivative over phi. Is something like this possible in sympy?

Function composition is available for [sympy functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638223/704028) and [it seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19050103/704028) directly in the `diff` as an argument, but the line (1) results in

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0771d7cb2d7b> in <module>
----> 1 f = R(phi) - p * n * R(phi)**2 * x1 - l * cos(R(phi))

TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define R as a function (`R=Function('R')` or `R=symbols('R', cls=Function)`. Or, since phi and R are indistinguishable in your example, you can just let symbol R represent what you know to be a function of phi and use `idiff`:

```
>>> idiff(f - (R - p * n * R**2 * x1 - k * cos(R)),(R, f),phi)  # dR/dphi
Derivative(f, phi)/(-2*R*n*p*x1 + k*sin(R) + 1)
>>> idiff(f - (R - p * n * R**2 * x1 - k * cos(R)),(f,R),phi)  # df/dphi
(-2*R*n*p*x1 + k*sin(R) + 1)*Derivative(R, phi)
```